# How do I put Java into GameMaker Studio?

Tags: java, android, game-maker

I'm playing around with GameMaker Studio and plan to use it for my next Android project. Yet I am not sure, how can I add java libraries ( jar files ) into it?

For example, if I want to implement LeadBolt's SDK into it... or if I have my own library for recording sounds coming into the microphone... can I add such libraries into GameMaker Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't - at least yet.

For the mobile system exports GM:Studio doesn't support extensions.
[In the roadmap](http://wiki.yoyogames.com/index.php/GameMaker%3aStudio_Roadmap), you can see that extensions are planned to be supported from version 1.3. The current version line is "1.1", so this feature is still quite some months away.

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=566396. However, this project is not official nor fully supported. I also don't know if it supports JAR.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

I see this is an old topic, but to anyone interested the way to do it is to right click on your extension, select open in explorer, then go to the android source folder and create a folder called libs (if it isn't already there), next put your jar file(s) in that folder and your sdk folder in there also. after that it should work, if not there is one more thing to do, in gamemaker go back to your extension and this time double click it and select the android tab, and add this line of code into the gradle dependencies section:

```
 compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

This works with GMS 1.3 and up and also for GMS 2 as well.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer here is no longer relevant or correct.

GameMaker Studio 1.4 and 2.0 (the most recent versions), as well as older 1.3, allow you to put any jar files you want included into your extension's *AndroidSource/libs* folder.

So this is the **PROJECT_FOLDER/extensions/YOUR_EXTENSION_FOLDER/AndroidSource/libs**.

Answer (score 0):

This function in early access 1.3. Now try open project in Eclipse and link library, it's very hard, but possible.

P.S. In early access added functions for C. It will be .so library.